# How to handle 100,000 requests concurrently in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am expecting to get 100,000 requests at least 100 of them would be concurrent. Each time I get a request, I am creating a new thread and destroy it once it's done using `pthread_exit()`. Using `pthread_detach` I am getting 99% success rate. Is there a better way than this?

```
pthread_t hilo;
// infinite loop
while ((client_sock = accept(server_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client_sockaddr, &len))) {
    struct ClientSocket socks;
    // some code...
    pthread_create(&hilo, NULL, func, &socks);
    pthread_detach(hilo);
    printf("\nSocket is listening for the next request...\n");
}
```

I heard `pthread_join` would be a better way to utilize resources without reaching the thread limit, but the way I am doing it is not concurrent.

```
pthread_t hilo;    
// infinite loop
while ((client_sock = accept(server_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client_sockaddr, &len))) {
    struct ClientSocket socks;
    // some code...
    pthread_create(&hilo, NULL, func, &socks);
    pthread_join(hilo, NULL); // it stops the main thread
    printf("\nSocket is listening for the next request...\n");
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Here's a good article to read:  http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html

Comment: Creating and destroying threads is a very heavy operation. Have you considered using thread pools?

Comment: 'I heard pthread_join would be a better way...'  no, almost never is pthread_join a better way of doing anything:(

Comment: 'I am creating a new thread and destroy it once it's done' - that too, is rarely a good way of doing anything.  Queue off the socket etc. to a pool of, say, 150 threads, as suggested by @DaveS

Comment: @DaveS, yes, actually that was my first approach. But I couldn't figure out how would I signal back upon the completion of the tasks without stopping/interfering the main thread infinite while loop. Any chance that you can give an example code in C?

Comment: @HafizTemuri why would you need to signal anything back?  Good threads are autonomous threads:)

Comment: 'example code' there are plenty examples of producer-consumer queues around, using condvars or semaphores.  All you really need to queue up is the server<>client socket as returned from the accept() call.

Comment: "*`pthread_detach(hilo);`*": You could create a thread already being detached by passing  to `pthread_create()` an attribute set accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> Each time I get a request, I am creating a new thread and destroy it once it's done

Don't: it's *not* a smart thing to do, because thread creation is a heavy-weight operation.

> I heard pthread_join would be a better way to utilize resources without reaching the thread limit, but the way I am doing it is not concurrent.

Correct. Whenever you see someone doing `pthread_create` immediately followed by `pthread_join`, you can tell that they have no idea what they are doing. The exact same result could be achieved (much more efficiently) by simply calling `func` directly.

> Any ideas would be appreciated!

You need a producer-consumer queue. The listening thread will `accept` connections and enqueue them for other threads in a (size-limited) thread pool. The other threads will dequeue one item of work, and perform `func` on that item. Then go back for next item, and so on.

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19847934/50617) producer/consumer implementation. But you can find many others with "producer consumer queue" search.